# Update a column while fetching record from the same table n Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

Im building an API, I need to count the number of requests processed for a user account, so everytime when I execute the select statement from the API_USERS table, I want to increment a column(req_count) in the same table by 1

so I have the number of requests made by that user account, is this possible to update the column while fetching a record?

Answer (score 0):

To increment a counter in a user table (if I understood well your problem) :

```
-- It will add 1 to request count for the user <your user id>
UPDATE api_users
   SET api_users.req_count = api_users.req_count + 1
 WHERE api_users.id = <your user id>
   -- Add your validity condition here
   -- ex: AND IS NOT banned
-- And returns all the infos of the user (Acts somthing like SELECT * FROM updated_api_users)
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: well, what I need is, I will be fetching a record from my table for every user request to see if they are valid user or not, if they are valid, Ill fetch their details using select statement, what I want to do now is, incrementing the count if the user is valid

Comment: Well, it's not very clear for me but I updated my example by adding the RETURNING part. This request will search for a user given it's id (you can use other criteria of course), and **if the user exists** or match your custom WHERE condition it will increment req_count by 1 and return all data for the given user. If the user if not found it won't do any update and return 0 rows. This request do all you've done with multiple ones. Just add your validity criteria in WHERE condition.

Comment: Does it solve your problem ? Please mark the thread as solved and the answer as helpfull if it is. Thank you